# Is it possible to truncate packets using iptables?

Tags: security, iptables

The first thing on my mind when setting up a new Linux server (dedicated or VPS) is how you can increase security. I was wondering if it is possible using `iptables` to truncate `icmp` packets.

If you send a packet using `ping -s` `-s` option stands for packet size.

```
#>ping www.google.com -s 100
PING www.google.com (216.58.209.164) 100(128) bytes of data.
72 bytes from bud02s21-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.209.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 (truncated)
72 bytes from bud02s21-in-f164.1e100.net (216.58.209.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 (truncated)
```

You see how I tried to send 100 bytes packets and how Google elegantly truncated to these 72 bytes in return.

Is this possible using iptables to do the same? Maybe using some iptables modules...

Answer (score 0):

From what I have researched in my kernel 4.2.0 that may not be the very latest... https://www.kernel.org/finger_banner

there is no iptables (netfilter) target module called like xt-TRUNCATE.h, or xt-CUT.h that would do the job of truncating packets probable and ideally somewhere in the mangle table.

Took me a while to also analyze the http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html to confirm that.

However, the process to create such a module should not be super difficult. It would take probable 200 lines of code or less since this looks like an average for all iptables target modules.